# using custom template engine how do I replace content with php

Tags: php, html

So, I have a template engine I made and I want to replace {pageBody} with contents from a PHP file, when I do it using the template engine it does not execute the PHP, rather it displays it in view source option.

TEMPLATE.PHP

```
<?php
class TemplateLibrary {
    public $output;
    public $file;
    public $values = array();

    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->file .= '.tpl';
        $this->output = file_get_contents('templates/'.$this->file);
    }

    public function replace($key, $value)
    {
        $this->values[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function output() {
        foreach($this->values as $key => $value)
        {
            $ttr = "{$key}";
            $this->output = str_replace($ttr, $value, $this->output);
        }
        return $this->output;
    }
}

index.tpl
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>{page_title}</title>
{page_style}
</head>

<body>
{page_header}
{page_body}
{page_footer}
</body>
</html>
```

HTML replace works fine, but PHP does not. Any ideas?

Comment: All you provided is a class and a template file. Can you add the code that is actually executing this?

Comment: sure. http://pastebin.com/QsFa5jWp

Comment: Try with eval. Because you display the php code not the run result.

Comment: mind giving me a example of how I would go bout's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rather scattered with your files and the list is incomplete.  I've listed all the files you've provided so far below.

@Jonathon above is correct, that you will need to use output buffering to capture the output of the PHP file and `include()` the file (so it gets executed) instead of using `file_get_contents()` (which does not execute the file).

[edit] I re-created all these files in my local environment and confirmed that @Jonathon's suggestion worked perfectly.  I've updated **dev/replacements.php** to include the suggested code.

Additionally, I added two more functions to your `TemplateLibrary` class : `replaceFile($key, $filename)` that does the `file_get_contents($filename)` so that you don't have to repeat it so often, and `replacePhp($key, $filename)` that performs an `include()` while capturing the output, so you can encapsulate the complexities of including a PHP file.

Good Luck!

**main.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'dev/dev.class.php';
require_once 'dev/templatelibrary.php';
$dev = new dev('netnoobz-billing');
$dev->loadLib('JS', 'js', 'jquery');

// template library and required files
$template = new TemplateLibrary('index');
require_once 'dev/replacements.php';


echo $template->output();
```

**dev/templatelibrary.php**

```
<?php
class TemplateLibrary {
    public $output;
    public $file;
    public $values = array();

    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->file .= '.tpl';
        $this->output = file_get_contents('templates/'.$this->file);
    }

    public function replace($key, $value)
    {
        $this->values[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function replaceFile($key, $filename)
    {
        $this->values[$key] = file_get_contents($filename);
    }

    public function replacePhp($key, $filename)
    {
ob_start();
include($filename);
$data = ob_get_clean();
        $this->values[$key] = $data;
    }

    public function output() {
        foreach($this->values as $key => $value)
        {
            $ttr = "{$key}";
            $this->output = str_replace($ttr, $value, $this->output);
        }
        return $this->output;
    }
}
```

**index.tpl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>{page_title}</title>
{page_style}
</head>

<body>
{page_header}
{page_body}
{page_footer}
</body>
</html>
```

**replacements.php**

```
<?php
$configStyleSheet = '<style type="text/css">'
                  . file_get_contents('styles/default/main.css')
                  . '</style>';
$pageHeader = file_get_contents('templates/header.tpl');
$pageFooter = file_get_contents('templates/footer.tpl');

#$pageBody   = file_get_contents('loaders/pageBody.php');
ob_start();
include('loaders/pageBody.php');
$pageBody = ob_get_clean();

$template->replace('{page_style}' , $configStyleSheet);
$template->replace('{page_title}' , 'NetBilling');
$template->replace('{page_header}', $pageHeader);
$template->replace('{page_footer}', $pageFooter);
$template->replace('{page_body}'  , $pageBody);
```

**loaders/pageBody.php**

```
<?php echo 'test'; ?>
```

[edit] added **loaders/pageBody.php** from OP's comment.

[edit] Updated **dev/replacements.php** to capture output buffer and use include on .php

Comment: pageBody.php is just a echo 'test';

Comment: Thanks, but is the entire file `echo 'test';` or `<?php echo 'test';` ? i.e. is it a valid php script?  If not, then it is treated as raw text and even using `include()` won't execute the file.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my post with your info, and have a new request in there as well.

Comment: the {} works fine in str replace, I tested it. Have any ideas how to fix though?

Comment: You are correct, misread the `"{$key}"` in your `output()` function.  I recreated all the above files in my environment and @Jonathon's suggestion worked perfectly - I've updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're using file_get_contents in your pastebin code but you should be using your template processor or PHP's include() instead. If you do $template->replace('{page_header}', $pageHeader), $pageHeader is just the source of the tpl and your template processor does not know that so it will just replace the tag with that source. Fix:

```
$pageHeader = new TemplateLibrary('header');
// ...
$template->replace('{page_header}', $pageHeader->output());
```

For the PHP files, you should call include() on the file, wrapped in output buffering, so you can pass the output of the PHP execution as the template variable, instead of the PHP source itself:

```
ob_start();
include('loaders/pageBody.php');
$pageBody = ob_get_clean();
/// ...
$template->replace('{page_body}', $pageBody);
```

Comment: I am talking about pageBody not "pageHeader" as pageheader works perfectly, so I don't need to fix pageHeader. I just need the PHP to execute.

Comment: I included a fix for that too, try it out?

Comment: Does not work, it just displays it two times, when I only need it once where its supposed to be.